# write string to excel using matlab and control the format

Tags: matlab

My question is so simple~
code is :

```
name={'ab','ac','ad','ae'};
xlswrite('outex1',name);
```

what I get :

a b a c a d a e

but I want:

ab ac ad ae

I try many different way, but I still not get what I want.
I am using 2013b version of matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name={'ab','ac','ad','ae'};
name = strjoin(name);
xlswrite('outex1',name);
```

Try this.

xlswrite in MATLAB in Mac has a issue. If you execute what you typed in Windows, it is working fine.

Comment: don't work, I got "a b blankcell a c blankcell a d blankcell a e"  just separated by blank cell between two of them.

Comment: are you using Matlab in Mac?

Comment: OK， I will try, i believe this is OK!